# Type or Namespace Error

Tags: c#, data-access-layer

I have two references in my application. In the BAL code i am able to use the namespace "using TestDAL;"

But I am not being able to use the namespace of BAL in my .cs page. This is the error i get,

> CS0246: The type or namespace name 'TestBAL' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And one thing in my bin folder too I only have the TestDAL.dll file. How do I insert TestBAL.dll file?

Can anyone help me with what can be possible reason?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Have you added Reference of BL in Project?

Comment: can you whole of the code of your file with the question

Comment: @Iti No i have added only preferences of DAL in BAL. But how can add BAL references in aspx.cs page?

Comment: Right click on your websoltion -> Go to Add reference and add TestBAL.dll to your project first

Comment: Please add some additional code, so we can know where exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[image: Add reference]

Then, click browse and add your .dll file:

[image: Browse]

That should help you, if not please leave some feedback.

You could also try using alias for your namespace like this:

```
using namespaceAlias = TestBAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create object of TestBAL objBAL = new TestBAL(); in your cs page. Check out, This codes gives any error or not.

Comment: > 'TestBAL' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'         This is the error after creating object of TestBAL